# How to create an android app which uses google maps?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

My objective was to create a basic app with google maps loaded inside it. I used the demo of sample maps to edit my xml, manifest and java(activiy) files. I created an api key using my SHA1 and also included its reference in the manifest. I also gave permissions for internet, opengl usage in the manifest. I am using Maps v2. I tried it on an Xperia Arc S and Google Nexus 4 and got different results in both. In the Arc S the app loads with no map but white screen with google logo and zoom in zoom out buttons. The screen flickers constantly. But in the Nexus 4 there is no flickering but all of the same as above. Please I need help as i am not able to load a map inside an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Sign you app with your keystore and create SHA1 for that keystore.
After that replace your new key with new keystore in app. Sign app with new keystore and run again..

PS- Please dont use debug.keystore. Create your own keystore for process

Comment: Still Getting the same error on both the devices as earlier. This time instead of the debug.keystore, i created my own keystore and signed the app with it. But in vain. Help

Comment: have you registered app with new SHA1 with new keystore on Google API console and changed you key in manifest?

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. i had entered the wrog package name when generating the api key

Comment: And yes that is important- its not working with the debug.keystore key. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check your key .

this tutorial may help .
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step

Comment: or  try to import and run sample map located in sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps